# How do I filter my model within itself twice in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm looking for some help with filtering my model twice in Django.

This is my current model:

```
class Medarbejder(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    ma = models.IntegerField(help_text="Indtast medarbejderens MA-nummer. (F.eks 123456)")
    fornavn = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Indtast medarbejderens fornavn.")
    efternavn = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Indtast medarbejderens efternavn.")
    holdnavn = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, help_text="Indtast medarbejderens hold.")
    delingnavn = models.ForeignKey('Deling', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    fagnavn = models.ForeignKey('Fag', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

The model is a model for employees (medarbejder). Now I wish to filter the teamname (holdnavn) with distinct, which I have accomplished. The next step is to then filter all the departments (delingnavn) within each teamname (holdnavn). So when I click on one teamname such as "GSU19", then I wish to get a list of all the departments within that teamname only.

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this? I am able to do it with slug and with pk, but both teamname and department are not a slug or a pk, so I'm abit lost to how to get the value in the url and filter again.

This is currently how the URL looks after I click on a specific teamname:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/hold/%3CQuerySet%20%5B%7B'delingnavn_id':%202%7D,%20%7B'delingnavn_id':%204%7D,%20%7B'delingnavn_id':%205%7D,%20%7B'delingnavn_id':%203%7D,%20%7B'delingnavn_id':%206%7D,%20%7B'delingnavn_id':%204%7D,%20%7B'delingnavn_id':%202%7D,%20%7B'delingnavn_id':%204%7D,%20%7B'delingnavn_id':%205%7D,%20%7B'delingnavn_id':%205%7D,%20%7B'delingnavn_id':%206%7D,%20%7B'delingnavn_id':%206%7D,%20%7B'delingnavn_id':%202%7D,%20%7B'delingnavn_id':%203%7D,%20%7B'delingnavn_id':%202%7D,%20%7B'delingnavn_id':%203%7D,%20%7B'delingnavn_id':%203%7D%5D%3E/
```

I'm getting all the department id's in the url..which is not what I want, I want them to be looped out in my template. Below is my current ListView:

```
class HoldDetailView(ListView):
    model = Medarbejder
    template_name = 'evalsys/medarbejder/list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HoldDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['medarbejder_hold'] = Medarbejder.objects.filter().values('holdnavn').distinct().order_by('holdnavn')
        context['medarbejder_deling'] = Medarbejder.objects.filter().values('delingnavn_id').distinct()
        return context

    def get_object(self, holdnavn=None):
        if holdnavn:
            medarbejder_deling = Medarbejder.objects.filter().values('delingnavn_id').distinct()
        else:
            medarbejder_deling = self.medarbejder_deling
        return render(self, 'evalsys/medarbejder/list.html',
                      { 'medarbejder_deling': medarbejder_deling})
```

Please ask any questions and I'll supply more code, I think my approach is incorrect, but I can't seem to figure out how to go about it.

For clarification:

Delingnavn = DepartmentName and is a foreign key to Departments.

Holdnavn = TeamName

Fornavn = FirstName

Efternavn = LastName

FagNavn = SubjectName

I wish to get all the teamNames, click on one, and see all the departments within that team.

**Update**

In template:

```
        {% for h in medarbejder_hold %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'evalsys:get_object' holdnavn=medarbejder_deling  %}">{{ h.holdnavn }} </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

And I've done it like this because usually I use slug or pk...

URLs:

```
path('', views.HoldDetailView.as_view(), name='home'),
path('hold/<str:holdnavn>/', views.HoldDetailView.as_view(), name='get_object'),
```

Comment: Well first you need to fix that URL, it makes no sense at all. Please show how you are generating it.

Comment: This is how it actually looks, its getting the queryset: https://prnt.sc/p7niwr

Comment: Please show how you are *generating* it. In other words, show the template.

Comment: I've updated my question with template and urls

Comment: Oh I forgot to change the name to ListView, but it is a listview I've made, I tried many things...

Answer (score 0):

This code is all over the place, unfortunately. `get_object` isn't ever called in a ListView, which is just as well; you can't render inside that method, it's for returning an *object*. And as I said, the URL itself is nonsense, you can't expect to just dump a queryset into a URL.

But it's not clear why you think you need to do either of these. If you want to filter by a specific `holdnavn`, then just pass that value into the URL and filter appropriately. (Note, I've changed the way you get the list of holdavn to make things a bit simpler.)

```
    {% for holdnavn in medarbejder_hold %}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'evalsys:get_object' holdnavn=holdnav %}">{{ holdnavn }} </a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

```
class HoldListView(ListView):
    model = Medarbejder
    template_name = 'evalsys/medarbejder/list.html'
    context_object_name = 'medarbejder_deling'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HoldDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['medarbejder_hold'] = Medarbejder.objects.filter().values_list('holdnavn').distinct().order_by('holdnavn')
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
       qs = super().get_queryset()
       if 'holdavn' in self.kwargs:
           qs = qs.filter(holdavn=self.kwargs['holdavn'])
       return qs
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know its very messy, but it's because I've tried so many things and gotten more and more confused. 

I see what you've done here and it makes sense, I also got to this point, but how do I then take all the departments (delinger) in the selected teamnavn (holdnavn) and show them? Surely, I must make another filter that says if the url is equal to a specific teamName (holdnavn), filter the departments in the specified team (holdnavn)?

Comment: But that is what this code is doing, inside `get_queryset`.

Comment: Oh okay, so I should replace the queryset with what I wish to get? So I would replace teamname (holdnavn) with departmentsnavn (delingnavn) to show all the deparments within the returned team?

Comment: I can get all the department names but not their unique values

https://prnt.sc/p7pm1s

Comment: I'm taking these from the actual department model, but not from the employee model, which I wish to do, I wish to filter the team names then show the departments within the teamname. I must be overlooking something..

Comment: Still havn't found out how to filter departments in the selected team.